# Animation messing up Tailwind styles

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a css file with the following animation:

```
.intro-x {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100px);
  animation: intro-x 1s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes intro-x {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

Button:

```
<button className="intro-x bg-slate-900 text-white hover:opacity-70">Click here!</button>
```

If I use this animation on the button, the `hover:opacity-70` style doesn't work!

**OBS: I'm using Next.js with Tailwind**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider having the "natural" state of the `.intro-x` be the `to` state of the `@keyframes`. This means we can remove `animation-fill-mode: forwards`, which stops the `to` state of the `@keyframes` from taking precedence, thus allowing other CSS to affect the `<button>`'s `opacity`.

```css
.intro-x {
  animation: intro-x 1s ease;
}

@keyframes intro-x {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<button class="intro-x bg-slate-900 text-white hover:opacity-70">Click here!</button>
```

Comment: I should have thought of that! But this creates another problem, the animation starts with opacity 1 and goes to 0 in the animation

Comment: The animation starts with opacity `0` and goes to `1` – run the provided snippet to see.

Comment: It starts at 1 when the page loads, then it goes to 0 and the animation starts to go to the default (1)